# Line chart legend border style using react-chartjs-2

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs

Is it possible to make the legend box of dashed line in line chart to have no dashed border?

I read about generateLegend() and legendCallback but I can't understand how it works in react-chartjs-2 together with React functional component. Also, I'm not sure if they can be used to change the border style of legend.

This is my sample code:

```
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";

const LineChart = () => {
    const data = {
        labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "Line 1", data: [10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30]
            },
            {
                label: 'Line 2',
                borderDash: [15, 5],
                data: [20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
            }],
    };

    const options = {
        legend: {
            position: legendPosition,
            align: legendAlign,
        }
    };

    return <Line data={data} options={options} />
};
```

This is sample of desired Line 1(red) and Line 2(grey dahsed)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `borderWidth:0` so, please remove `borderDash: [15, 5]` and add `borderWidth: 0,`. Or you can completely **replace** data with below:

```
const data = {
    labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"],
    datasets: [
        {
            borderWidth: 0,
            label: "Line 1", data: [10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30]
        },
        {
            label: 'Line 2',
            borderWidth: 0,
            data: [20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
        }],
};
```

**Update**

You have to use `borderWidth: 0` in data.datasets and this is mandatory for you requirement. Moreover, you can pass `options={options}` into `Line` to have more configuration for legend like `legend background-color` or `legend font-color` or `legend boxWidth` and so on.

**Here is the [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chartjs-2-example-j5sk6?file=/src/LineDemo.js)**

**Here is the output picture**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping. However, I can't use borderWidth: 0 because that will cause the line to be too thin and that's not the desired design. Also, I can't remove borderDash: [15, 5] as I need "Line 2 " to be dashed line. Do you have another way?

Comment: Hi, I have added a picture that I got when I run project with borderWidth 0. Is this ok?

Comment: Hi. I cannot use borderWidth:0 because the line is too thin, and I need to follow the design requirement. I have added a picture too. Not sure if you can see the legend box of Line 2 is having dashed border. I want it to be normal box like the one of Line 1

Comment: can you please share your full code so that I can reproduce your issue on my side?

Comment: Here's the code in codepen [link](https://codepen.io/pw12/pen/RwWzJmb) though it's not working but you'll get the idea. Sorry, it's my first time coding in code pen and asking in stackoverflow. Hope it helps in reproducing at your side

Comment: Hi, After running your code I am not getting any dashed line. Please check **Picture 2**. Also, Please try: https://codesandbox.io/s/zwxo5l6jvl?file=/src/LineDemo.js:249-790 may be it helps you

Comment: I'm so sorry, I missed out some setting. I have fixed it. Please try again if you don't mind. If using the link you sent, you will see the dash by changing the value of borderDash to [15,5]

Comment: great you have fixed it

Comment: NO! Maybe I didn't make myself clear. Let me reiterate,  I want a dashed line but I don't want the legend box to have dashed border. How to do that without using borderWidth:0 ?

Comment: hi I have updated my answer. Please check **Update** section